# Looking for a “Convex hull” like algorithm, 2D at a time, for modeling clothes

Tags: modeling, python, add-on, geometry, photorealism

I am trying to put realistic clothes on characters created with MB lab, and I have decided that if I could have a version of the convex hull algorithm that worked on two dimensions at a time instead of all three, it would create decent clothes that wouldn’t look like the character was in shrinkwrap. Does anyone know of such an algorithm that exists?

What I mean is probably best explained by going through the mesh along one or two axes (probably Z and Y), cross sections at a time, and creating a convex hull for the results of each cross-section.

Comment: Does it have to be Blender?  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_2/index.html

Comment: Well, this is the Blender Stackexchange but I guess not. Will try to check out, though I prefer Blender strongly: it’s what I know.